Image in the RawImage widget is failing to load in golden widget testing
I'm facing an issue with a golden widget test where an image displayed using the RawImage widget is not appearing in the screenshot. Despite using extended durations for pumpWidget, pump, and pumpAndSettle, the image does not render. I have attached the code for displaying the image and the test case for reference.
RawImage widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawImage-class.html
pump widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pump.html
pumpWidget method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpWidget.html
pumpAndSettle method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html
Steps taken:
Created a sample application to display the image using image raw bytes in the RawImage widget.
Used the following code:
 class ImagesToBytes extends StatefulWidget {
  final Uint8List bytes;
  final int width;
  final int height;
  ImagesToBytes(
      {required this.bytes, required this.width, required this.height});
  @override
  _ImagesToBytesState createState() => _ImagesToBytesState();
}

 class _ImagesToBytesState extends State<ImagesToBytes> {
  ui.Image? _image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createImage(widget.bytes, widget.width, widget.height);
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _createImage(Uint8List pixels, int width, int height) {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    ui.decodeImageFromPixels(pixels, width, height, ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888,
        (ui.Image image) {
      setState(() {
        _image = image;
      });
      completer.complete(image);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _image != null
        ? RawImage(
            image: _image,
            width: widget.width.toDouble(),
            height: widget.height.toDouble(),
          )
        : CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}

Used the following code to generated raw bytes from the image:
 Future<Uint8List?> loadImageToRawBytes(String assetPath) async {
  // Load image from assets
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
  final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  // Decode image
  final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
  final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
  final ui.Image image = frameInfo.image;
  // Convert image to raw bytes
  final ByteData? byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
  return byteData?.buffer.asUint8List();
 }

This is following golden widget testcase:
 void main() {
  testWidgets('Image to Bytes Golden Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
          MaterialApp(
            home: ImagesToBytes(bytes: rawImageData, width: 284, height: 177),
          ),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 60));
      //await tester.pump(Duration(seconds:60));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 60));
    });

    await expectLater(
      find.byType(ImagesToBytes),
      matchesGoldenFile('goldens/rawimage_bytes_pumpandsettle.png'),
    );
  });
  }

Run update goldens command to take the screenshot
the screenshot from the update goldens command:

Output screenshot from the application:

This is the image used in the application to generate raw bytes:

Expected results:
The image should be fully rendered and visible in the golden screenshot taken during the test.
Actual results:
Despite the long duration waits (60 seconds), the image does not appear in the screenshot. Only the surrounding UI elements are visible.
